# Core data structure use multiple entities or not?

Tags: xcode, core-data

I have a Core Data model and I am trying to figure out how to structure it.

Lets say I have a `Recipe`. it has a `name`, `title`, `image` and 5 ingredients.

Would I make a recipe entity with `recipeName`, `title`. Then an `Image` entity with `recipeName`, `imageURL`.

Then an `Ingredient` entity with `recipename`, `ingresient1`, `ingredient1measurwment`, `ingredient2`, etc...

Or would I do it all under a recipe entity (but what happens if theoretically i create a recipe with 100 ingredients?

Also, I use `recipeName` because I think thats how you link them up?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on your question, I would create two different entities.

`Recipe`,`Ingredient`

where `Recipe` has a to-many relationship with `Ingredient`.

So, `Recipe` will have some attributes (the attributes you need) and a simple relationship called for example `toIngredients`. `toIngredients` is a to-many relationships. In other words, a recipe could have zero (or one if you want) ingredients.

In the same way, `Ingredient` has some attributes. In addition, it has a to one (**inverse**) relationship called `toRecipe` to its `Recipe`. Here you could decide also to have a to-many if your recipes could share ingredients but it strictly depends on what you want to model.

About rules for relationships, `toIngredients` has a cascade rule. When you delete a recipe, all its ingredients will deleted too. On the contrary, `toRecipe` will be of type nullify.

Here a simple schema of it.

[image]

where `toIngredients` is set as follows:

[image]

and `toRecipe` is:

[image]

Notice that *optional* flag for `toRecipe` is unchecked. This means an ingredient can exists only if a recipe exists. If you don't follow this rule, Core Data will complain about this.

About the image, it depends on how bigger are the images. Follow Marcus Zarra rules for deciding how to design your model [Core Data - Storing Images (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090028/core-data-storing-images-iphone).

Comment: So core data adds as many ingredients as you want?  It automatically associates with the recipe, so i dont need a recipe ID?

Comment: @waf04 you don't need an id in this case

Comment: Also what is cascade as opposed to nullify?

Comment: @waf04 documentation is your friend ;) https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html

Comment: I notice they have many to many here. Would it make sense to ise many to many for ingredient to recipe? If ten recipes have ingredient1 as an ingredient, would it save room?

Comment: @waf04 yes. You could also have many-to-many. See, what I wrote in my answer *Here you could decide also to have a to-many if your recipes could share ingredients but it strictly depends on what you want to model.*

Comment: I´ve been looking for an explanation like this for a long time, excellent flexaddicted...simple and excellent!, i learn about relationships...in my case i have 3 entities and they are not suppose to have common property´s, but i will have a save and a load button, so i should wrap all the entities into an object right? and create the relationships like you explain here? thanks

Comment: @Japa Happy to help ;) Could you explain better your goal? Maybe ask a question in SO and put the link to it here. Maybe I can help somehow.

Comment: Hello flexaddicted, could you see this post please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498307/core-data-inheritance-and-relationships

Comment: @LorenzoB What is the code one would use to associate the ingredient with the recipe in this example?