# Core Data Inheritance and Relationships

Tags: core-data

I´m a little confused about inheritance and relationships in core data, and I was hopping someone could drive to the right path. In my app i have created 3 entities, and none of them have (and are not suppose to have) common properties, but there´s gonna be a save and a load button for all the work that the user does.  From my understanding I need to "wrap" all the entities "work" into an object which will be used to save and load, and my question is, do I need to create relationships between the entities?  Because I have to relate them somehow and this is what make sense to me.  Is my logic correct?

I'm implementing a budget calculator, and for the purpose of everyone understand what my issue is, I´m going to give an practical example and please correct me if my logic is incorrect:

Let´s just say you are a fruit seller, and because of that it´s normal to have a database of clients and also a fruit database with the kinds of fruit you sell. From my understanding I find two entities here:

**Client** with properties named: `name`, `address`, `phone`, `email`, etc.

**Stock** with properties named: `name`, `weight`, `stock`, `cost`, `supplier`, etc.

**TheBudget** with properties named: `name`, `amount`, `type`, `cost`, `delivery`, etc.

I didn´t put all the properties because I think you get the point.  I mean as you can see, there´s only two properties I could inherit; the rest is different. So, if I was doing a budget for a client, I can have as many clients I want and also the amount of stock, but what about the actual budget?

I´m sorry if my explanation was not very clear, but if it was..what kind of relationships should I be creating?  I think `Client` and `TheBudget` have a connection. What do you advise me?

Comment: I think you should consider adding a 'receipt' entity. That way you can track the purchases of clients and also generate budgets based on what was purchased in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not entirely correct, but some parts are on the right track. I've broken your question down into three parts: relationships, inheritance and the Managed Object Context to hopefully help you understand each part separately:

### Relationships

Relationships are usually used to indicate that one entity can 'belong' to another (i.e. an employee can belong to a company). You can setup multiple one-to-many relationships (i.e. an employee belongs to a company and a boss) and you can setup the inverse relationships (which is better described with the word 'owns' or 'has', such as 'one company has many employees).

There are many even more complicated relationships depending on your needs and a whole set of delete rules that you can tell the system to follow when an entity in a relationship is deleted. When first starting out I found it easiest to stick with one-to-one and one-to-many relationships like I've described above.

### Inheritance

Inheritance is best described as a sort of base template that is used for other, more specific entities. You are correct in stating that you could use inheritance as a sort of protocol to define some basic attributes that are common across a number of entities. A good example of this would be having a base class 'Employee' with attributes 'name', 'address' and 'start date'. You could then create other entities that inherit from this Employee entity, such as 'Marketing Rep', 'HR', 'Sales Rep', etc. which all have the common attributes 'name', 'address' and 'start date' without creating those attributes on each individual entity. Then, if you wanted to update your model and add, delete or modify a common attribute, you could do so on the parent entity and all of its children will inherit those changes automatically.

### Managed Object Context (i.e. saving)

Now, onto the other part of your question/statement: wrapping all of your entities into an object which will be used to save and load. You do not need to create this object, core data uses the NSManagedObjectContext (MOC for short) specifically for this purpose. The MOC is tasked with keeping track of objects you create, delete and modify. In order to save your changes, you simply call the `save:` method on your MOC.

If you post your entities and what they do, I might be able to help make suggestions on ways to set it up in core data. You want to do your best to setup as robust a core data model as you can during the initial development process. The OS needs to be able to 'upgrade' the backing store to incorporate any changes you've made between your core data model revisions. If you do a poor job of setting up your core data model initially and release your code that way, it can be very difficult to try and make a complicated model update when the app is in the wild (as you've probably guessed, this is advice born out of painful experience :)

Comment: +1 Good effort to answer an unclear question. I think the first two sections miss the mark a bit, though. Relationships don't necessarily indicate ownership -- they only indicate some sort of connection between two pieces of data. Also, your description of inheritance is very general; it's hard to see how it answers the OP's question.

Comment: @Caleb, thanks for the suggestions. I didn't feel like the concept of inheritance really spoke to what the OP needed, so I just included a general description of it for completeness. I wanted to make sure I addressed all topics included in the question. Agreed relationships don't necessarily indicate ownership, but since that was more relevant to the question, I didn't want to give an overly generic answer. Seems to be a fine line of how 'generic' an answer should be.