# Core Data multiple objects for single entity

Tags: ios, core-data

I am new to the Core Data. I am trying to create an employee database using Core Data. I store the user name and his birthday in an entity `Employee` and the employee can have **multiple** phone numbers. So I have created another entity `PhoneNumbers` to store the phone number. I have made the relationship for the two entities. But when I try to insert two phone number for the employee, only the second phone number have the relationship to the employee.

I don't know how to alter my core data model.

[image]

This is how I insert the data's to the Core Data.

```
  NSManagedObject *entry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[entry setValue:@"Suresh" forKey:@"name"];
[entry setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"birthdate"];

NSManagedObject *phoneEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PhoneNumbers" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[phoneEntry setValue:@"9600492944" forKey:@"phone"];

[phoneEntry setValue:entry forKey:@"owner"];
[entry setValue:phoneEntry forKey:@"phone"];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"hi %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

NSManagedObject *phoneEntry1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PhoneNumbers" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[phoneEntry1 setValue:@"1234567890" forKey:@"phone"];

[phoneEntry1 setValue:entry forKey:@"owner"];
[entry setValue:phoneEntry1 forKey:@"phone"];

if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"hi %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core data structure use multiple entities or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072475/core-data-structure-use-multiple-entities-or-not)

Comment: See the link I provided. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have not set relationship properly. As you can see in the screenshot that you have attached, *it shows single arrow pointing to phone number (like this >) instead of 2 arrows (like this >>).* So click the Employee entity, click the phone relationship. You can see the toolbar on the right, click the relationship button (third one) set the **Type as to Many**. It will solve your problem. Also if you want that the phone number entity related to the person automatically gets deleted, then set the **Delete Rule to Cascade**. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your relationship has to be a one to multiple - from your screenshot I see you have a one-to-one relationship. Redefine the relationship and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In your coredata model, select the relationship phone in employee entity and change the type of it to "To Many"... it will create the relation between Employee and PhoneNumbers as one-to-many relationship.

After changing the above, you can store multiple phone numbers for an employee...