# how to store photos and videos in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, alassetlibrary

I need to add video from default photos and images to my app and that videos must be stored in core data.
One more thing i want to know where the datas are really storing in core data and how can i see the saved datas?
If possible then give me the schema also.

Comment: Hi welcome to so, please narrow your question down with examples and what you have done.

Comment: i am very new to ios and i am not yet started this task i need a basic idea about this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please try searching before asking questions as you will find the answer.  [This question has been asked and answered many, many times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090028/core-data-storing-images-iphone/2098401#2098401).